# How to represent a door in Raphael / SVG

Tags: svg, raphael

I want to be able to represent a door as a triangle, but with the smaller side curved as per the image below.

How can I do this with SVG / Raphael? I understand how to make a triangle but I am unsure what to do with the curved section.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a path, like any other Raphael path (see the [Raphael documentation for path](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path)), and include an elliptical arc (A) in its definition.

Here is a JSFiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/XzPzE/362/

Comment: Yep, [elliptical arc](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) is what the OP is searching for.

Comment: Any idea how I do that though? Do I have to create the line, and then the arc, or can I include it all as one command?

Comment: You can create one path with the line and the arc. I edited my answer to show you a working example on JSFiddle, hope it helps!